# How to query the object which has manytomany field point to them in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-queryset

I have two models User and Company

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField max_length=50)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField( max_length=40)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
```

I want to get all the company which has some users are following them.
Something like

```
Company.objects.filter(has_following = True)
```

How can i  do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `related_name` when declaring a M2M relationship:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(Company, related_name='followers')
```

Then, you can query it using:

```
>>> Company.objects.exclude(followers=None)
```